# Появление скрытого поля, при выборе в select

Tags: jquery, select

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть форма:

```
<form>
            <div id="dostavka" class="name_textfield">Способ получения</div>
                    <select name="dostavka" id="dostavka">
                        <option value="vibor" id="vibor"> Выберите</option>
                        <option value="ofice" id="ofice"> В нашем офисе</option>
                        <option value="kurer" id="kurer"> Доставка курьером</option>
                        <option value="express" id="express"> Экспресс почта</option>
                        <option value="russianpost" id="russianpost"> Почта России</option>
                    </select>

            <div style="display: none;" id="adress_menu">
                    <div class="name_textfield">По адресу</div>
                        <select name='adress' class="form_text_field" id="adress">
                            <option value="Adress">Геодезическая 23, оф. 2</option>
                        </select>
            </div>

            <div style="display: none;" id="adress_text">
                    <div class="name_textfield_2">Адрес доставки</div>
                        <input name='adress_text' type='text' value="" class="form_text_field">
            </div>              
    </form>
Как сделать чтобы при выборе в select "ofice" появлялось скрытое поле "adress_menu", а при выборе "kurer", предыдущее поле исчезало, а появлялось "adress_text"?
вот так не работает :(
    $('form').change(function(){
    if($("#dostavka").val() == "ofice") div("#adress_menu").slideDown(400);
        else if($("#dostavka").val() == "kurer") div("#adress_menu").slideDown(400);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

А чего за div() такой?

```
if($("#dostavka").val() == "ofice") /*div*/$("#adress_menu").slideDown(400);
        else if($("#dostavka").val() == "kurer") /*div*/$("#adress_menu").slideDown(400);
```

ну и change надо на #dostavka вешать а не form

Да и как скрыть по id див скрыть/показать догадаетесь?

Вообще почитайте документацию http://docs.jquery.com/

Comment: Спасибо. Первое что я сделал когда наткнулся на проблему - это почитал доки. Там очень сложно написано. Я нашел ошибку (id) у div и select были одинаковые + удалось написать код. Сейчас не могу придумать как написать, чтобы при выборе другого варианта, строка всплывала на том же месте где и предыдущая. Сейчас получается, если я выбираю последовательно разные варианты из select, то строки появляются друг под другом. Подскажите, пожалуйста как это сделать (синтаксис)

Comment: вот код:
  $(document).ready(function() {
function nameFunct()  {
var singleValues = $("#dostavka").val();
switch(singleValues)
{
case ("ofice"): $('#adress_menu').slideDown(400).$('#adress_text').slideUp(400);
break;
case ("kurer"):$('#adress_text').slideDown(400);
break;
}                
}
$("select").change(nameFunct);
nameFunct();
});
</script>

Comment: сделал наконец-то:)